# jquery datatables custom search form

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm creating to jquery datatables custom search form.The form contains inputs, checkboxes, selectboxes. But not posting any data. I have tried a few methods but I have not been successful.

```
$('#search-form').on('submit', function () {
    var datas = $(this).serializeArray();

    $.each( datas, function( i, data ) {

      table.columns(i).search(data.value).draw();

    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for better understanding of the question

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have to submit any form, just use button on click. Look at my solution below, click on the filter button to expand the input box, then try type in something and click the search button. The datatable will re-draw after that.

The code is self explanatory, let me know if you need further clarifications.

```js
$("#filter-button").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $('#filter-body').slideToggle(100);
});

$("#btnSearch").click(function(e){
  var table = $('#custTable').DataTable();
  var txtCustName = $("#txtCustName").val();
  var txtIntroducer = $("#txtIntroducer").val();
  var txtNRIC = $("#txtNRIC").val();
  var txtNickName = $("#txtNickName").val();
  var txtAddress = $("#txtAddress").val();
  var txtPhone = $("#txtPhone").val();
  var txtRemark = $("#txtRemark").val();

  table
    .columns(1).search(txtCustName)
    .columns(2).search(txtIntroducer)
    .columns(3).search(txtNRIC)
    .columns(4).search(txtNickName)
    .columns(5).search(txtAddress)
    .columns(6).search(txtPhone)
    .columns(7).search(txtRemark)
    .draw();
});

$('#custTable').DataTable({
  responsive: {
    details: {
      type: 'column',
      target: 'tr'
    }
  },
  columnDefs: [
  {
    className: 'control',
    orderable: false,
    targets:   0
  }],
  "dom": 'iti',
  iDisplayLength: -1
});

$('#custTable thead th:first-child').css({'background-image':'none'});

$("#custTable a.cust_id").on('click', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="filter-container">
<button class="accordion" id="filter-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">Filter Customer</button>

<div id="filter-body" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body filter-body">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3" style="text-align:initial;">
<div class="filter-group">
<label for="txtCustName">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="txtCustName">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3" style="text-align:initial;">
<div class="filter-group">
<label for="txtIntroducer">Introducer</label>
<input type="text" id="txtIntroducer">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3" style="text-align:initial;">
<div class="filter-group">
<label for="txtNRIC">NRIC</label>
<input type="text" id="txtNRIC">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3" style="text-align:initial;">
<div class="filter-group">
<label for="txtNickName">Nick Name</label>
<input type="text" id="txtNickName">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3" style="text-align:initial;">
<div class="filter-group">
<label for="txtAddress">Address</label>
<input type="text" id="txtAddress">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3" style="text-align:initial;">
<div class="filter-group">
<label for="txtPhone">Phone</label>
<input type="text" id="txtPhone">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3" style="text-align:initial;">
<div class="filter-group">
<label for="txtRemark">Remark</label>
<input type="text" id="txtRemark">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="text-align:initial;">
<div class="filter-group">
<button class="btn btn-success" id="btnSearch"><i class="mdi mdi-filter-outline"></i> Search</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<table id="custTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer dtr-column" cellspacing="0" width="100%" aria-describedby="custTable_info" role="grid" style="width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr role="row"><th class="control sorting_asc" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 13px; display: none; background-image: none;" aria-label=""></th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="custTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 74px;" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending">Name</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="custTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 121px;" aria-label="Introducer: activate to sort column ascending">Introducer</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="custTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 67px;" aria-label="NRIC: activate to sort column ascending">NRIC</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="custTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 124px;" aria-label="Nick Name: activate to sort column ascending">Nick Name</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="custTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 101px;" aria-label="Address: activate to sort column ascending">Address</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="custTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 79px;" aria-label="Phone: activate to sort column ascending">Phone</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="custTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 93px;" aria-label="Remark: activate to sort column ascending">Remark</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="custTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 94px;" aria-label="Actions: activate to sort column ascending">Actions</th></tr>
</thead><tbody><tr role="row" class="odd">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=27">abed</a></td>
<td>abba</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="" class="btnDelete" id="27"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="even">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=28">accure</a></td>
<td>abandon</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="" class="btnDelete" id="28"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=29">async</a></td>
<td>acura</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="" class="btnDelete" id="29"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="even">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=30">bbb</a></td>
<td>brazil</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="" class="btnDelete" id="30"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=20">john</a></td>
<td>alan</td>
<td>1234</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="" class="btnDelete" id="20"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="even">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=26">pencil</a></td>
<td>taylor</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="" class="btnDelete" id="26"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=21">steve</a></td>
<td>alan</td>
<td>123321</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="" class="btnDelete" id="21"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="even">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=25">taylor</a></td>
<td>zayn</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="" class="btnDelete" id="25"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=24">zack bro</a></td>
<td>zack</td>
<td>123131</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="" class="btnDelete" id="24"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```